# Copy results of `org-export` directly to clipboard

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I often find myself doing this:

- Selecting a region of text in an `org` file.
- Calling `org-md-export-as-markdown`.
- Selecting the converted text in the temporary buffer (can't just do `mark-whole-buffer` since for these purposes I'm obviously not interested in the empty Table of Contents I get).
- Killing the temporary buffer and going back to where I was.

**EDIT**: Here is my **question**: How can I write a function that will, after selecting a region of text, do all of that for me? In other words, I want a function which will take a region from an `org` file, copy the result of `org-md-export-as-markdown` to the clipboard, and return to the `org` file I called the function from.

**Some related attempts**:

*John Kitchin* has [a post](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2016/06/16/Copy-formatted-org-mode-text-from-Emacs-to-other-applications/) where he does something similar to what I'm doing. But he uses `texutil`, since he wants the output in a format that `org` won't export to. I'm assuming what I need would be much simpler than that.

*Oleh Krehel* has a function that copies the converted `html` from a region as part of [his emacs config](https://github.com/abo-abo/oremacs) (see [here](https://github.com/abo-abo/oremacs/commit/6c86696c0a1f66bf690e1a934683f85f04c6f34d)). But he uses `xclip` which I believe is not available for macOS.

Abo-abo's function is here

```
(defun ora-org-to-html-to-clipboard ()
   "Export region to HTML, and copy it to the clipboard."
   (interactive)
   (org-export-to-file 'html "/tmp/org.html")
   (apply
    'start-process "xclip" "*xclip*"
    (split-string
     "xclip -verbose -i /tmp/org.html -t text/html -selection clipboard" " ")))
```

I presume I can modify something like this by replacing

```
xclip -verbose -i /tmp/org.html -t text/html -selection clipboard
```

with

```
pbcopy < /tmp/org.html
```

but I can't quite get it to work.

**My own, failed attempt so far:**

This was my blind attempt at adapting the function `ora-org-to-html` to use `pbcopy` instead. (Adapting it to use `org-md-export-to-markdown` would be fairly straightforward, I think.)

```
(defun org-to-html-to-clipboard ()
   "Export region to HTML, and copy it to the clipboard."
   (interactive)
   (org-export-to-file 'html "/tmp/org.html")
   (apply
    'start-process "pbcopy" "*pbcopy*"
    (split-string
     "pbcopy < /tmp/org.html")))
```

Running this does create the file `/tmp/org.html` but the contents aren't sent to the clipboard. Further, the `html` file contains the entirety of the buffer I run the function from (which I gather is what the original function was supposed to do) rather than just the selected region. Finally, this function requires creating a temporary file, rather than just using the temporary buffer that `org-mode` generates with the `*-export-as-*` functions.

---

*I'm completely illiterate when it comes to `elisp` so any suggestions, no matter how elementary they seem, would be most welcome.*

Comment: The question is too broad. And only one question per post, please. Specific Q&A is what SE is about. There is no doubt at least one specific, operable question in there somewhere - please consider digging it out and posting it instead of this one.

Comment: I did some editing following your advice. Let me know if this is still too broad.

Comment: OK, thanks. Hope you get some specific answers.

Comment: Note that `xclip` _is_ available on macOS. `brew install xclip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this here in case it helps anyone else. Following [a suggestion](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/e98yyf/send_output_of_orgmdexportasmarkdownstraight_to/fahi3ny?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) by [u/ImmediateCurve](https://www.reddit.com/user/ImmediateCurve/) over at Reddit, I ended up with the following function, which does what I want (it uses `simpleclip.el` since I mostly rely on it for interacting with the system clipboard on macOS):

```
(defun apc/org-md-to-clipboard ()
  (interactive)
   (save-window-excursion
    (let ((org-export-with-toc nil))
      (let ((buf (org-export-to-buffer 'md "*tmp*" nil nil t t)))
        (save-excursion
           (set-buffer buf)
        (simpleclip-set-contents (buffer-string))
        (kill-buffer-and-window)
        )))))
```

Comment: If you satisfied with the answer, why not accept it?

Comment: Why not indeed?